# Google maps move markers together

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I move the markers together? I use the bindTo, but it put them the same position. But I need to keep the distance between them.

```
marker1.bindTo('position', marker2, 'position');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The result:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(editMarkers[0], 'dragstart', function() {
  latDiff = editMarkers[0].getPosition().lat()-editMarkers[1].getPosition().lat();
  lngDiff = editMarkers[0].getPosition().lng()-editMarkers[1].getPosition().lng();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(editMarkers[0], 'drag', function() {
  editMarkers[1].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(editMarkers[0].getPosition().lat()-latDiff,editMarkers[0].getPosition().lng()-lngDiff));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save them all in an array. Make an event for when you move one and also move the others with it (modify their coordinates).